# Swagger UI does not show nested fields in schema recap

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-6.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to document an API with Swagger-UI. I have a lot of nested models in some response. In the schema list at the bottom of the page, a schema A does not allow unfolding all its nested objects (at one point, showing only nested object description instead of its field list), although when unfolding another schema B which contains model A in its fields, allow unfolding all of nested schema of A.

This behaviour seems inconsistent, is it expected ? Does anyone has already encountered and fixed this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My experience is the generated YAML/JSON schema is correct.

BUT

The UI has a limit on the displayed level of nested schemas. I guess the maximum level is set to two and it seems to be hard-coded in the renderer.
If your model is deeper, the UI will render only the description and the examples will result in strings instead of objects.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7437

I have difficulties finding information on that in the available documentation.

There are also issues reported, such that the wrong rendering can be caused by ordering.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5972